# Как правильно написать условие для if? discord.py rewrite PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, бот, discord.py

Имею такой кусок кода:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_join(self, member):
    cursor.execute(f'SELECT channel_for_greeting FROM public."prefixDB" WHERE guild_id = \'{member.guild.id}\';')
    chan = cursor.fetchone()
    conn.commit()
    
    cursor.execute(f'SELECT true_or_false FROM public."prefixDB" WHERE guild_id = \'{member.guild.id}\';')
    yes_or_not = cursor.fetchone()
    conn.commit()
    
    channel = self.bot.get_channel(chan[0])
    print(yes_or_not[0]) 
    
    if f'{yes_or_not}' == str('True'):
        emb = discord.Embed(
            title = f'Приветствуем Вас на сервере {member.guild.name}!',
            description = f'Каждый участник этого сервере равен перед другими. Поэтому настоятельно просим ознакомиться с правилами сервера\nЗаранее благодарим Вас за вежливость и адекватность.',
            colour = discord.Color.green()
        )
        emb.set_thumbnail(
            url = member.avatar_url
        )
        emb.set_footer(
            text = f'{member.id}' + ' Приятного времяпрепровождения!',
            icon_url= 'https://github.com/xzartsust/holo_bot/blob/master/files/image/id.png?raw=true'
        )
        await channel.send(f'{member.mention}', embed = emb)
    else:
        print('no')
```

В переменную yes_or_not заносится значение из БД True или False
Если в БД True то когда новый пользователь заходит на сервер в определенный канал будет направляться поздравления, если False то соответственно ничего не будет

Я написал else: print('no') для проверки.
Так вот когда пользователь заходит то мне в консоль выводит no, то есть у меня не правильно написана условие.
Перепробовал несколько вариантов, но все равно выводит no.

Какое условие подойдет?

Comment: `yes_or_not` точно `True` или `False` содержит?

Comment: Да, в БД можно занести только True или False

Comment: [Не воспроизводится](https://repl.it/repls/FocusedUnpleasantPublishers)

Comment: Если yes_or_not точно True или False, что тогда выводит эта строка : print(yes_or_not[0])? С условием все в порядке.

Comment: == str('True')  строка . а тру по идее это бул. принтаните type(      yes_or_not) что там будет ?       #замените эти значения на инт 1/0  и не парьтесь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `cursor.fetchone()` всегда возвращает кортеж (или None, если данных больше нет).

Поэтому вам необходимо заменить строку
`if f'{yes_or_not}' == str('True'):` на
`if f'{yes_or_not[0]}' == str('True'):`

Хорошая статья по этой теме на [хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/321510/).

Comment: Я уже разобрался протупил, в принт написал yes_or_no [0] а в условии не написал